# Combine two group by queries with query builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have two similar groupBy queries this:

```
DB::table('orders')
    ->join('users', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->groupBy('users.sponsor_id')
    ->selectRaw('users.sponsor_id, sum(points) as total_points_a')                
    ->get();
```

and this one:

```
DB::table('orders')
    ->join('users', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('users as leader', 'users.sponsor_id' = 'leader.id')
    ->groupBy('leader.sponsor_id')
    ->selectRaw('leader.sponsor_id, sum(points) as total_points_b')                
    ->get();
```

I don't see a way how to combine them smartly. However, I need as end result the `total_points_a` and `total_points_b` for each `sponsor_id`. Not every `sponsor_id` is in the result of both queries.

I managed to merge both results with Laravel collections, but this is quite slow. Is it possible to somehow merge the queries, so that one gets `sponsor_id, total_points_a, total_points_b` as the result of one query?

Comment: Maybe a good candidate for subquery join. Laravel has `joinSub` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins (check under subquery joins)

Comment: Have you tried to use the methods of the left/right/cross join?

Answer (score 0):

As user3532758 suggested, `subquery joins` is what I needed.

In order to really show all all results, I had modify the first query to fetch all users using a left join. From this, I could create a left join sub.

```
$secondQuery = DB::table('orders')
    ->join('users', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->join('users as leader', 'users.sponsor_id' = 'leader.id')
    ->groupBy('leader.sponsor_id')
    ->selectRaw('leader.sponsor_id, sum(points) as total_points_b');

$result = DB::table('users')
    ->leftjoin('orders', 'orders.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->groupBy('users.sponsor_id')
    ->selectRaw('users.sponsor_id, sum(points) as total_points_a, bonus_b.total_points_b')    
    ->leftJoinSub($secondQuery, 'bonus_b', function ($join) {
               $join->on('users.sponsor_id', '=', 'bonus_b.sponsor_id');
     })            
    ->get();
```